# Method to animate a stroke along a curve

Tags: bezier-curves

I am trying to create an effect like the moving map in Indiana Jones or the trace of a CRT oscilloscope.   I would like to set up a few curves and have a stroke appear along the curve at a constant rate relative to the length of the curve.  If I could lock an object to the head of the curve that would be optimal.

Comment: Have a look at [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jBRbqtpkI8I) from about 5:30 onwards and see if it helps.

Comment: John Eason, Yes this is exactly what I was looking for.  If you would like to describe that process in the answer section I will accept it.

Comment: Now added as requested.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a Bezier Curve and set it to the required path using subdivide to add points as required. Click the green curve (1) on the properties panel and then the Geometry drop down (2).
In the Bevel section leave the type at Round then increase the Depth (3) slightly. Click to open Start & End Mapping (4) and set both Factor Start and End to 0.
Go to the first frame in the timeline. Right-click on Factor Start and select 'Insert Keyframe'. The dot after the Factor Start entry (6) will change to a diamond shape.
Go to your required end frame on the timeline, set Frame Start to 1 and click the diamond to add a key frame. Run the animation.

[image]